# Destroy Session on the logout Simplesamlphp

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I have installed the library and so far everything working very perfectly. I have a question regarding the session destroyed, is there any way to destroy all the active sessions of the application?

**getLogoutURL()** logout me from the idp provider however when I retry to access my custom application it still shows that my sessions are active.

My code:

```php
<?php
require_once('lib/_autoload.php');
$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');
if ($as->isAuthenticated()) {
    $attributes = $as->getAttributes();
    $email      = $attributes['useremailaddress'][0];
    $authemail  = $email;
    $idpaccess  = "idpaccessauth";
    $session    = SimpleSAML_Session::getSessionFromRequest();
    $session->cleanup();
    $_SESSION['emailemp']  = $authemail;
    $_SESSION['idpaccess'] = $idpaccess;
    redirect("" . SITE . "data.php");
} else {
    echo "Not authenticated";
    $as->requireAuth();
}
```

thank you

Comment: Try the [logout method](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp-api.html#logout)